# Display a column value through DataRelation in c#

Tags: c#, lookup

I've lately been migrating from Delphi to C#. I find C sharp very powerful and the IDE is awesome. There are some unaccustomed stuff though.

On the database side I have two inner-related tables. Students and Categories. I keep `CategoryID` in the students table as foreign key. I want to link a `DataGridView` to the Students table.

When I add a new student I want to be ale to also choose the student's `Category` from the dropdown list that list of available Categories. In Delphi we have an opportunity to add a lookup column to table so that it keeps `CategoryID` in the backgound but displays `CategoryName`.

How do I do it in C#? Is it possible through DataRelation? If yes, how?

Comment: Seriously, it's not *that* hard to choose the correct web site for your questions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... You don't mention data technology (Linq etc.) or interface (e.g. Winforms, Webforms etc,) so it is far too hard to help you....

But I have done something similar and I would treat it as two queries, first do a `select category.name` to populate the drop down box, then something along the lines of

`int _temp = select category.id where category.name == dropdownbox.selectedtext`

then in your insert command for the student, you simply provide the int _temp.

Comment: This is not very robust and will not allow for duplicate names etc, and I am sure someone on here will have a much better answer, but again, without knowing technologies involved, hopefully this will put you on the right track.... possibly just not the fastest one!

Comment: Oh yeah, data technology is ADO.NET and it's just a windows forms application.